# Подключение к ORACLE из PHP

Tags: oracle, php, linux

Здравствуйте, появилась необходимость подключатся к базе Oracle на удаленном, из PHP, для чтения данных. До этого я с Oracle никогда не работал, поэтому копаясь в примерах из интернета, пытаюсь как то подключится, но не выходит. PHP код который я выполняю:

```
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password',
 '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521))) (SDU=5844) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = XE)))');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();exit($e['message']);
} else echo 'ok';
```

Где: username - имя пользователя, password - пароль 0.0.0.0 - IP адрес удаленного сервера (реальные имя, пароль и IP естественно другие).

В результате получаю такую ошибку

> ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

На сервере где выполняется PHP в качестве ОС стоит Linux, в качестве клиента установлен Oracle Instant Client. Кто может подсказать в чем может быть проблема, и где я ошибся при подключении к базе, и как вообще можно протестировать подключение к удаленному серверу?

Comment: Похоже, что клиент с сервером по разным портам работают.

Comment: Нас интересует ведь только порт на сервере базы ?  это 1521А про какой порт на клиенте вы говорите ?Хотя сколько я с напарником не пробовали разобраться, пришли к выводу что скорее всего на удаленном сервере не отвечает никто, написали в поддержку что бы разобраться.

Comment: Вам точно нужен service name , может sid?
Просто не могу вспомнить реализован ли доступ по сервису в драйвере к php